# how to use a single checkbox with wpalchemy?

Tags: wpalchemy

I can find some little example on using multiple checkboxes, but no one about using a single checkbox in a wpalchemy metabox. Anyone can help me please?

No docs about this topic on the wpalchemy site..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WP Alchemy comes with example files that show the usage of virtually all field types;

Example;

```
<?php $mb->the_field('cb_single'); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="abc"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state('abc'); ?>/>
```

https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy/blob/master/wp-content/themes/mytheme/metaboxes/checkbox-meta.php#L9

Comment: I already tried this approach but didn't work. I'll try again.
But also some WPAlchemy_MetaBox class undocumented methods seems to be useful for this and don't work or I'm not able to make them work for some reason.

For example, the_checkbox_state, get_the_checkbox_state and is_selected don't work properly in my context. Don't know.

Also I'd really like to understand what some constants are used for. For example:

WPALCHEMY_FIELD_HINT_CHECKBOX and
WPALCHEMY_FIELD_HINT_CHECKBOX_MULTI